# Usage of the word 'lest'

Tags: word-usage

How do I rewrite the sentence "**Write the book quickly or you will not get the license to publish it**." using the 'lest' .

Comment: You can look that up. This is homework, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would slightly change the meaning but you could write:

> Write the book quickly lest you do not get the license to publish it

Lest is equivalent in meaning to 'in case' so this becomes more of a warning against something that might happen, instead of the definite cause and effect that the original sentence implied.

Lest is not a common word in normal usage so the new sentence sounds overly posh or dramatic.